# Sticky navbar UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I achieve the following UI using [this](https://github.com/couds/react-bulma-components) package?
[image: Sample Image]
Both of the navbars are fixed. Can anyone shed some light on it?
This code shows only one navbar fixed top.

```
<Navbar
      style={{ backgroundColor: "#ffffffa8" }}
      fixed="top"
      active={this.state.active}
    >
      <Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Item renderAs="a" href="/">
          <img src="images/dv.png" alt="Dew Ventures" />
        </Navbar.Item>

        <Navbar.Burger
          active={this.state.active}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        />
      </Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Menu active={this.state.active}>
        <Navbar.Container position={"end"}>
          <Navbar.Item href="/">Home</Navbar.Item>
          <Navbar.Item href="/products">Products</Navbar.Item>
          <Navbar.Item href="/about"> About Us</Navbar.Item>
          <Navbar.Item href="/contact"> Contact Us</Navbar.Item>
        </Navbar.Container>
      </Navbar.Menu>
    </Navbar>
```

> Note that if I add another `<Navbar fixed="top">` it will overlap the
>   current Navbar resulting in nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used react-bulma-components but after I had a very quick look at the code I think you could try adding some css properties on the Navbar elements to push down second Navbar. Like this example:

```
<Navbar fixed="top" style={{height: 30}}>
   ... some code
</Navbar>
<Navbar fixed="top" style={{top: 30}}>
   ... some code
</Navbar>
```

Or, remove the prop fixed and add 'position: fixed' to the style prop on the second Navbar. like this:

```
<Navbar fixed="top">
   ... your code
</Navbar>
<Navbar style={{position: 'fixed', top: 'the-pixel-height-of-the-first-navbar'}}>
   ... more code
</Navbar>
```

I hope this could be to any help for you.

Comment: this look working in theory, your second code block, let me implement it, thanks

Comment: Okay, theoretically and practically this worked but had to add extra CSS (obviously) for consuming it the whole width.